# Proving that $u_{n}\in\mathbb{Z}\forall n\ge 0$, such that $\det \begin{bmatrix}u_{n} & u_{n+1} \\ u_{n+2}&u_{n+3}\end{bmatrix}=n!\forall n\ge 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, determinant

> Define a sequence $u_n\forall n\ge 0$ such that $u_{0},u_{1},u_{2}=1$ and $\det\begin{bmatrix}u_n & u_{n+1} \\ u_{n+2} & u_{n+3}\end{bmatrix}=n! \forall n\ge 0$. Prove that $u_n\in\mathbb{Z}\forall n\ge 0$.

As of now I have just gone on to find the values of the sequence to see if they form a pattern. The first few terms come out to be $1,1,1,2,3,5,8,15, 48, 105$. No obvious pattern is visible. Also induction is used, will have to be multi counter induction, and I am not familiar with its application. Also if we try to replace $n$ by $n-1$, we get following expressions.

$$\begin{aligned}u_{n}u_{n+3}-u_{n+1}u_{n+2}&=n!\\ u_{n-1}u_{n+2}-u_{n}u_{n+1}&=(n-1)!\end{aligned}$$

On subtracting we get the equality $u_{n}(u_{n+3}-u_{n+1})-u_{n+2}(u_{n+1}-u_{n-1})=(n-1)^{2}(n-2)!$. I can not see how to proceed. Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think http://oeis.org/A006882 is what you are looking for. The first terms are 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 8, 15, 48, 105.

Comment: Why did you delete the post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686542/points-of-non-differentiability-of-fx-arccosx-sin-lambda-x-lambda-i/3687826#3687826 It was perfectly fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is
$$
 u_2 = 1 = 1 u_0 \\
 u_3 = 2 = 2 u_1 \\
 u_4 = 3 = 3 u_2 \\
 u_5 = 8 = 4 u_3 \\
 u_6 = 15 = 5 u_4 \\
 u_7 = 48 = 6 u_5 
$$
and generally, $u_n = (n-1) u_{n-2}$ for $n \ge 2$. It follows that
$$
u_n = (n-1)!! = (n-1)(n-3)(n-5) \cdots
$$
for $n \ge 1$ where $!!$ denotes the [“double factorial.”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) It is now easy to verify that 
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}u_n & u_{n+1} \\ u_{n+2} & u_{n+3}\end{bmatrix} =
u_n u_{n+1}\det\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ {n+1} & {n+2}\end{bmatrix} = u_n u_{n+1} = n! \, .
$$
Apart from the initial term $u_0 = 1$ this is [A006882](http://oeis.org/A006882) in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences®.

Comment: Remaining to do the proof that it is actually this sequence. The citation listed on OEIS for "Satisfies a(n+3)*a(n) - a(n+1)*a(n+2) = (n+1)!" is Putnam Contest.

Comment: @AHusain: *“Remaining to do the proof that it is actually this sequence”* I am not quite sure what you mean. As I said above, it is easy to verify that $\det\begin{bmatrix}u_n & u_{n+1} \\ u_{n+2} & u_{n+3}\end{bmatrix} = \ldots = n!$.

Answer (score 0):

An idea is from $u_{n}u_{n+3} - u_{n+1}u_{n+2}= n!$, see if $u_{n}| n!+u_{n+1}u_{n+2}$ for small values of $n$ and induct on that Too.  Let $A(n)=\begin{bmatrix}u_n & u_{n+1} \\ u_{n+2} & u_{n+3}\end{bmatrix}$

Suppose that  for all $k \leq n$: $A(n)$ has integer entries  and that  $A_{11}(k)| k!+ A_{2,1}(k)A_{1,2}(k)$.

Then prove that this still hold for $k=n+1$.